# Deserializing an object that contains a single list with gson

Tags: android, rest, gson, deserialization

I have the following json I want to deserialize:

```
{
    "locations": [{
        "id": 17,
        "account_id": 11,
        "name": "The Haunted Lexington",
        "radius": 100
    }]
}
```

(In this particular instance, there's only one `Location`, but there can be many).

I deserialize this using Gson with the following code:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
LocationList ll = gson.fromJson(jsonString, LocationList.class);
```

I have the following classes defined:

```
public class Location {

    @SerializedName("id")
    private long mId;

    @SerializedName("account_id")
    private long mAccountId;

    @SerializedName("name")
    private String mName;

    @SerializedName("radius")
    private int mRadius;

    public long getId() {
        return mId;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return mName;
    }
}
```

and:

```
public class LocationList {
    @SerializedName("locations")
    private List<Location> mLocations;
}
```

The thing is, I have a bunch of these "dummy" classes that contain a single object that's a list of other objects (e.g. `UserList`, `MessageList`, etc...)

What I'd like to do is have the above json parsed somehow so I can skip defining the intermediate class definition of `LocationList`, like so:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

// Use the same json as above, but skip defining the superfluous "LocationList" class
List<Location> ll = gson.fromJson(jsonString, "locations", ArrayList<Location>.class);
```

Is there a way I can do this, perhaps by providing a custom deserializer?

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem not long ago, and solved it like this

```
// Parse the JSON response.
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);

List<Location> locations = new ArrayList<Location>();

/*
 * Create a Location object for every JSONObject in the response,
 * and add it to the list.
 */
for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
    JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);

    Location location = new Gson().fromJson(jsonObject.toString(),
            Location.class);
    locations.add(location);
```

The approach here is to loop over every Location in the locations array in the JSON, extracting them one by one and then adding them to a list.

The JSON I worked with had a list as root object, so you probably can't use this `JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);`. Something like this might better suit your situation

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);
JSONArray locationsJsonArray = jsonObject.get("locations");
```

I have not tested these last 2 lines, but I think you get the idea.

I hope you can use this to solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently using a simple method to achive your goal:

```
private static <T> List<T> getList(final String jsonVal, final String listTag, T t) {
    try {
        JsonObject jsonObject = (JsonObject)(new JsonParser()).parse(jsonVal); // root JsonObject. i.e. "locations"
        JsonArray jsonArray = (JsonArray)jsonObject.get(listTag);

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();
        List<T> list = gson.fromJson(jsonArray, new TypeToken<List<T>>() {}.getType());

        return list;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unexpected json structure!", e);
    }
}
```

**Example usage:**

```
final GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
final Gson gson = gsonBuilder.create();

String jsonString = "{\"locations\":[{\"id\":17,\"account_id\":11,\"name\":\"The Haunted Lexington\",\"radius\":100}]}";

List<Location> list = getList(jsonString, "locations", new Location());
```

This method should be used for your orther classes, such as:

```
List<User> userList = getList(jsonString, "users", new User());
List<Message> messageList = getList(jsonString, "messages", new Message());
```